# Punctuation of "But you know, Bob, you, too, played an important role"

Tags: punctuation

> But you know, Bob, you, too, played an important role.

Is this actually how one would punctuate this sentence? Given how commas work, I think this is correct, but it looks very bizarre.

Comment: While you can set off _too_ with commas, it isn't required, and this sentence would be better off without them.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could do even worse: “But you know, Bob, that, somehow, this, too, will be forgotten.” I'd _seriously_ recommend against ever punctuating like that in practice; but it is, in theory, perfectly permissible punctuation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet unless, you, are, imitating, the, acting, style, of, William, Shatner, in, his, role, of, Captain, Kirk.

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, that's a perfectly punctuated sentence.

Here's why:
We put a comma before a name of a person when we're addressing them (You know, Bob, that's not going to work./ Come here, Allan. I love you, Sandra.), and we MAY put commas before and after "too". It doesn't violate any rules of punctuation.

Comment: Not my downvote I hasten to add, but can you say *why* that punctuation is "perfectly punctuated"?

Comment: Because we put a comma before a name of a person when we're addressing them (You know, Bob, that's not going to work./ Come here, Allan. I love you, Sandra.), and we MAY put commas before and after "too". It doesn't violate any rules on punctuation. So whoever gave this a down-vote should probably be prepared to explain their action.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter will see your comment. If you edit your answer, he or she may reverse the vote.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Downvotes don't bother me a bit. I joined this site to get as well as share information, not to collect votes. :-D

Comment: +1. While it's not the epitome of style, there's nothing grammatically wrong; and what's more, I'm sure that have seen constructions like that in published writing before.

Comment: @Niel, there wouldn't be anything grammatically wrong even if commas were added between every single word in the sentence, because commas are _punctuation_, not _grammar_. :-)

Comment: I recommend to add your explanation in the comment to your answer, not for the sake of downvotes, but to make the answer informative.

Comment: @Louel, you should add your comment to the body of the answer itself: it is an intrinsic and indispensable part of the explanation, which is precisely what an answer should be.

Comment: It's been done. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: commas tend to delimit parenthetical phrases, and various other features of syntactical construction, do they not?

Comment: @Niel, yes they do. But grammar is a feature of _language_ itself, which is primarily oral. Punctuation is an artificial convention of writing, which is just an attempt to represent a codified version of language. Punctuation is part of writing and arguably of orthography, but none of punctuation, orthography, or writing itself is part of grammar per se.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I think I see; grammar is a feature of the spoken language (either realised, or suppressed in the course of producing written communication), while punctuation is part of the notational conventions for producing the written transcript. Your description of the difference is perhaps the first helpful one I've been given.

Comment: I'd like to say that the downvote was probably given as a knee jerk response. Having included an explanation, the answer is now more complete. +1 from me!

Comment: I haven't voted, but I'd agree with Bradd's 'While you can set off _too_ with commas, it isn't required, and this sentence would be better off without them' rather than 'that's a perfectly punctuated sentence'. But it does give me a chance to mention John Lawler's marvellous 'It's grammatical, but that's the only good thing that can be said about it.'

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference. I'd put those commas there, but wouldn't have a problem if I didn't see them there.

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer to see an em dash or a colon after Bob, thus:

> But, you know, Bob—you, too, played an important role.

Or

> But, you know, Bob: you, too, played an important role.

Typographic and punctuation arguments re dashes are put forward [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/15/mind-your-en-and-em-dashes-typographic-etiquette/). (Spot the deliberate(?) inconsistency!)

Comment: +1. But in case the  OP wants British English: a spaced en dash is generally used instead of an unspaced em dash.

Comment: @nxx - Increasingly so, I know, but I think this is a shame. And it's not a nationally accepted standard. Publishers have their own rules about this (see New Hart's Rules on this). While I can see the argument for using en dashes instead of brackets, or to join two related parts of a sentence, I prefer to use em dashes in situations such as this, where a break in thought followed by a continuation of the same line of thought where it broke off, is to be conveyed.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest placing either a colon or a dash after *Bob*: "You know, Bob:..." or "You know, Bob—...".

Comment: How does your answer differ from [the earlier one given by Leon Conrad](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/152308/5438)?

Comment: You can always show your agreement with another answer by upvoting it.

Comment: I didn't see his answer.